# New mySQL query or POST info from page to page?

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a php page that pulls a few hundred characters (distributed amongst 8 columns) of data from my database.  It's displayed on page one, but it needs to be available on page two as well.  I am already submitting a form in order to make said page transitions.

What I'm wondering is if it is more efficient (or preferred for some other reason) to POST the data from the first page to the second, or if I should query the database for each page?  There is another query for a different table on the first and second page as well, if that makes a difference.

Thank you very much!
Billy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a truly small amount of data you have retrieved on your first page load, it may be more efficient to store it in `$_SESSION` rather than requerying it on subsequent pageloads. You should not post it to other pages through `$_POST`, however, as that would require sending all of the data down to the client browser and rendering it in HTML as some kind of form which would then get sent back up to the server in `$_POST`. `$_SESSION` is the better option.

The purpose of `$_POST` is to supply user input from client to server, while the purpose of `$_SESSION` is to persist data between the client's pageloads on the server side. That is exactly your situation.

Always, the best way to know for sure is to profile your page loads with a tool like [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). Profile execution times when requerying and storing the data in `$_SESSION` to see which is more performant.

Comment: "You should not post it to other pages through $_POST, however, as that would require sending all of the data down to the client browser and rendering it in HTML as some kind of form which would then get sent back up to the server in $_POST."  
Doesn't that happen when I display the data anyway?  It's being displayed on both pages.  
Thank you for your response!  
Billy

Comment: @JeepFreak In this case you happen to be displaying it on the first page. In many other cases you'll display only a subset or none of it and use it internally only. My point is, and I should have stated it more clearly, that the purpose of `$_POST` is to supply user input from client to server. The point of `$_SESSION` is to persist data between the client's pageloads on the server side. That is exactly your situation.

Comment: I see, I see.  Thank you for explaining.  Sessions would be easy to implement, this page will only be used by me and the information does not pose a security concern, so that probably makes the most sense.  I'll unset the variable when I'm done with it.  Thanks again @Michael

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you'd better to have your own queries in each page. You might lose some data while you want to **POST** them to the new page if you have lots of information. By the way, you won't be able to modify and change your query and its data grid.

On the other hand, storing lots of data in **PHP Sessions** is not very easy if your data is so much. In addition you must be careful about security risks about working with sessions everytime.

But, when you a few information, using PHP Sessions is a good idea as Michael said. Also, if you are sure you don't need to chage your information, you can take a copy from your table of information using jQuery and then, print them in a new window using `window.open` function.

Don't forget that these were just my ideas and solutions. Read other's comments too.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mohammad!  In your opinion, how much data is "a lot" for a session variable?

Comment: JeepFreak, absolutely I can't tell how much data is "a lot". It's not countable as you know ... But imagine you have about 100 records and 5 item as their fields for each one. Is it easy for you to create `sessions` for these 500 value, and after that, read them again one by one ... ?